# Very strange published papers on Mach's Principle

Tags: general-relativity, inertia, machs-principle

I have recently come across a set of peer-reviewed conference papers (https://petermarkjansson.com/research/machs-principle/) reporting observations of electromagnetic markers of Mach's Principle. In short, anomalies in the discharge of batteries are observed, and the claim is that they are related to the angular position of major astronomical masses (Earth, Sun, Moon, Virgo Supercluster).

Holding an MSc in Physics myself, these claims seem to me as outright crackpottery.
However, these claims do not come from some random forum, but from papers that are technical in their *form*, and publicly presented at conferences by an academic.

Now, were they just papers about malfunctioning equipment, it would only be a matter of some conferences' standards on how (un)interesting contributions they are willing to accept.
The potential crackpottery arises when the authors relate the anomaly to some Mach Effect, without stating what physical quantity is the source, or why such a large effect has gone unnoticed so far, or why it only affects their specific electric appliance.
Moreover, I was not able to find other works along the same research line.

**So, my question is:** have I been missing a legitimate line of research up until now, or have I walked into what is some reiterated malpractice (to say the least) in peer-review scrutiny?

NOTE. I am aware that some red flags can be spotted: the targeted conferences are minor; the research topic, as well as the citations, look quite isolated; the emphasis on contributions from undergraduate students is unusual; the team's `Mach Field Sensor/Detector` is patented, which might have pushed some non-scientific interests. However, I am not interested in these aspects here, nor in the motive of the pattern; I am only interested in the physical claim being made, plus (if possible) a judgment on the review process.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence. I'm sure you can publish a conference paper claiming the moon is literally made of green cheese *somewhere*, if you try hard enough (e.g. if you organize your own conference!)

Comment: Note that the conferences were organized by the American Society of Engineering Education and the IEEE, so the reviewers' expertise (to the extent that conference proceedings are subject to review) would be strongly biased towards the electrical engineering  / sensor development side of the papers, rather than any astrophysical claims.

Comment: @alephzero I did not find the authors among the organizers/chairs. Maybe they have insiders, but this is just my speculation.

Comment: @rob Yes, maybe they checked the $V=RI$ stuff of their expertise and overlooked the rest. But I think that the argument is so enormous and potentually ridiculous that it should strike any scientific/technical reader.

Comment: @rob The fact that one of the conferences focuses on education is even more appalling to me.

Comment: I'm not appalled. A regional conference for an educational society (which is probably what "ASEE Zone 1" means) usually has an undergraduate-research section. The point of the undergraduate papers is not necessarily that they are groundbreaking, or even correct, but that preparing them is good education for the undergraduates, who then get to network with professionals at the conference. A faculty member who uses such an easy-access venue to pad his publication list is not fooling anybody; if his students haven't figured this out on their own, someone at the conference will politely tell them.

Comment: @alephzero https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXHNzNxV6RM

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Having looked at the web site what stands out is the misuse of the concept of Mach's principle; the failure to give quantitative information; the failure to engage the obvious questions; the apparent lack of a self-critical mindset.

Comment: I've hidden some comments that discussed a previous version of this answer. Friendly reminder that [our warning against name-calling](https://physics.stackexchange.com/conduct) "includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to content." If folks want to discuss site policy, please use [meta].

Answer (score 11):

According to page 5 of [this](https://www.asee.org/documents/conferences/annual/2021/2021-Authors-Kit.pdf), there is a registration fee.

Also if the electrical effect depended on the positions of the planets, it would vary slowly and smoothly, but the undergraduates experiments show an effect that starts and ends quickly and lasts about 300 seconds.

So whatever caused the effect it's unlikely to be related to Mach's principle.

Comment: What's the significance of the registration fee? (In my experience, registration fees are normal at the kind of conference where you can publish peer reviewed papers. I don't know if it's common in physics, but in computer science and probably also in engineering it's the norm.)

Comment: @ Nathaniel  It gives a temptation for the organisers to accept a paper, especially if they are short of contributions and need to cover their costs.  In this case the peer review didn't appear to work for some reason.

Comment: @JohnHunter Yes. And based on my (short) experience, it is also not rare that small conferences are short of submissions. Then, one should ask oneself if it is better to accept few papers, or to include unscientific stuff that someone could... see. But this is outside the Physics of the questions - though very interesting!